# Getting value from entry box in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The following is the functional issue I'm dealing with. I'm not sure how long 'frank" will be since in the real program he's being created from a line of text. What's happening is 2 things. 1) in this small demonstration, it isn't waiting for the button press and it just prints empty values for what should reflect an entry. 2) When I use this function to print to a csv, I'm getting the entry box instance as a string. I assume that fixing one will fix the other. Thanks.

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

def getThat(top,bottom):
    bottom = bottom.get()
    print ('%s: "%s"' % (top, bottom))


root = Tk()
root.title("This space intentionally left blank")
root.minsize(900,200)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

frank = ["beany", "beans", "beens", "not beets"]
x=0
for f in frank:
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=frank[x]).grid(column=x+1, row=2)  
    addMore = StringVar()
    moreBeans = ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=addMore)
    moreBeans.grid(column =x+1, row =3)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Do It", command = getThat(frank[x], addMore)).grid(column=1, row=5, pady=5)
    x+=1
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you were wondering what the fix was, I'll post it here

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk
import nltk
import csv

frank = ["beany", "beans", "beens", "not beets"]
letters = ["a","s","d","f"]
newInputs=[]
allTheBeans=[]
def getThat(newInputs):
    for inputs in newInputs:
        allTheBeans.append((inputs[0], inputs[1].get()))
    print allTheBeans
def makeBoxes (root, frank):
    for x in range(0, len(frank)):
        Label(mainframe, text=frank[x]).grid(column=x+1, row=2)
        moreBeans = ttk.Entry(mainframe)
        moreBeans.grid(column =x+1, row =3)
        moreBeans.insert(0,letters[x])
        newInputs.append((frank[x],moreBeans))
    return newInputs

def clearItOut(clearList):
    del clearList [:]

root = Tk()
root.title("This space intentionally left blank")
root.minsize(900,200)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
madeBoxes=makeBoxes(mainframe, frank)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Do It", command = lambda *a: getThat(newInputs)).grid(column=1, row=5)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Undo It", command = lambda *a: clearItOut(allTheBeans)).grid(column=1, row=6)
root.mainloop()
```

I added some other stuff to make sure I was understanding those principals as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
 ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Do It", command = lambda *a: getThat(frank[x], addMore)).grid(column=1, row=5, pady=5)
```

should fix it

the problem is its being called on creation ... by putting it in a lambda it wont ca;ll until the click

alternatively and probably better form would be to create a function

```
def OnClick(*args):
    return getThat(frank[x], addMore)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Do It", command =OnClick).grid(column=1, row=5, pady=5)
```

since you are in a loop you might need to do something like

```
def OnMyClick(x,addMore,*args):
    return getThat(frank[x], addMore)
import functools
for x,f in  enumerate(frank):
   ...
    my_listener = functools.partial(OnMyClick,x,addMore)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Do It", command = my_listener)
    ...
```

Comment: Love the idea, but the fix you suggested gives me a list index out of range error. I can fix it by saying that larry=frank[x] and replacing frank with larry, but then it only gives the final entry value (all that prints is "not beets: "green beans""). I need to retrieve all of them. Thanks

Comment: Still only giving me the last entry value.

Comment: see second edit ... its because addMore was the one in the loop ... now its locked to the right instance by functools.partial (same with x)

Comment: Even with the edits, it's still only providing the final value.

Comment: By the way, I really do appreciate the help.